# Как вынести обработчик событий кнопки в другой класс? Java

Tags: java, swing

У меня есть 3 класса (3 отдельных файла).

1. просто запуск приложения
2. Класс прорисовывает форму с одним JLabel и JButton.

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся текст JLabel, но так чтобы обработчик событий был в 3м класе. Как это организовать?

1)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Form();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Form {
    JFrame jForm;

    Form(){
        jForm = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        jForm.setBounds(500,500,200,200);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Text");
        jp.add(jl);
        JButton jb = new JButton("Button");
        jp.add(jb);
        jForm.setContentPane(jp);
        jForm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

3)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Controller implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener {
    private final JLabel label;

    public Controller(JLabel label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText("Hello");
    }
}


jb.addActionListener(new Controller(jl));
```

Comment: Мне нужно из класа Controller изменить в классе Form Jlabel, но как мне передать туда ссылку на форму?

Comment: @rayvoid дополнил ответ.